# OneDrive - uploading file using Graph API results in occasional 416

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, microsoft-graph-files

I'm using the "get an upload session, upload chunks" method. Generally, it's working. I'm using a chunk size of `640 * 1024`, which according to the docs is legit.

Occasionally I'll get a response code of `416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)`. The [Upload large files with an upload session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) documentation is not very clear on what to do when I get one:

> On failures when the client sent a fragment the server had already received, the server will respond with HTTP 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable.

I am keeping track in my code of the chunks, which I believe I am doing correctly. Is there another reason I might get a `416`? I will say that I was getting crappy upload speeds from my ISP at this time.

If I do get a `416`, should I just retry it? Or should I ignore it, and believe the docs, that (for some reason) that chunk has already been received?

Comment: You shouldn't retry a 416 since it believes it already received that chunk. I would continue and then validate the file is correct once it completes.

Comment: Thank you. I think I just discovered that Volley (the library I'm using on Android) is retrying my requests. If I keep Volley from doing retries, I get much better results. I will  also do as you suggest by ignoring the 416s if I see them.